# How can I rewrite a URL using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite a URL using a .htaccess file. For example:

http://www.nettsky.live/register.php --to--> http://www.nettsky.live/registrer

How can I achieve that using .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the below code in .htaccess and then call URL: `http://www.nettsky.live/registrer`. It will point to the `register.php` page

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: *"registrer"* is not the same as *"register"*.